How does lmList calculate AIC?
I'm using the lmList function in the lme4 R package to fit the following model:
mod.list <- lmList(record ~ log(LL)*site | species, data = dat, family=binomial)

My understanding is that lmList fits a separate model for each species as follows:
mod.single <- glm(record ~ log(LL)*site, data = dat, family=binomial)

I wish to use the AIC for the list of models for statistical inference.
How is the AIC computed by lmList? How does it relate to the AICs of each model in the list?
Somewhat analogous to ANOVA and post-hoc pairwise comparisons, it appears that a few of the single models can contribute the most to the lmList AIC.

I have discovered that AIC for the multispecies list model is the sum of the AICs for the separate models.
Is there anything else we need to know?
